# UnregisterKeys() method not executing in apache geode native client

Tags: c#, geode

After successfully subscribing to the region and setting up CacheListener and finishing using it, the `UnregisterKeys()` method in
`Region.GetSubscriptionService().UnregisterKeys(new List<string>() { key })` seems not to be working as per screenshots.
After below code execution, the events still fire in `AfterUpdate(EntryEvent<TKey, TVal> ev)`.

How do I unsubscribe from the region correctly?

I am using Apache Geode Native 1.10.0
running it on .NET WPF Framework 4.6.0

Image 1 - Getting interested Keys:

[image]

Image 2 - Executing UnregisterKeys and checking for Interested keys again.

[image]

Creating CacheFactory:

```
cacheFactory.Set("log-file", _serviceName + "Geode.log")
            .Set("log-level", "info")
            .Set("statistic-sampling-enabled", "false")

            .Set("name", _serviceName)
            .SetPdxReadSerialized(true)
            .Create();
```

Creating Pool:

```
_cache.GetPoolManager()
            .CreateFactory()
            .SetSubscriptionEnabled(true)
            .AddLocator(_host, _port)
            .SetFreeConnectionTimeout(new TimeSpan(5000))
            .Create();
```

Answer (score 2):

Still working on a repro for this, but can say for sure this doesn't appear to be an issue with C++ talking to Geode Native from the latest develop branch.  The following test code passes:

```
auto cache = createTestCache();
auto poolFactory =
    cache.getPoolManager().createFactory().setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
cluster.applyLocators(poolFactory);
poolFactory.create("default");
auto region = setupCachingProxyRegion(cache);
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CacheableKey> > keys;
keys.push_back(std::make_shared<CacheableInt32>(123456));

region->registerKeys(keys, false, true);

auto attrMutator = region->getAttributesMutator();
auto listener = std::make_shared<SimpleCacheListioner>();
attrMutator->setCacheListener(listener);

region->put(123456, "foo");
region->put(123456, "bar");
region->put(123456, "baz");
region->put(123456, "qux");

region->unregisterKeys(keys);
auto stillInterested = region->getInterestList();
EXPECT_EQ(stillInterested.size(), 0);

EXPECT_EQ(listener->getCreateCount(), 1);
EXPECT_EQ(listener->getUpdateCount(), 3);
EXPECT_EQ(listener->getInvalidateCount(), 0);
EXPECT_EQ(listener->getDestroyCount(), 0);

cache.close();
```

*In theory*, the C#/.net Geode Native client is just wrapping the C++ code with minimal changes, so the language shouldn't be an issue here, but of course I won't know 'til I try.  Likewise, I don't recall any changes being made in this part of the code since the 1.10.0 drop, but again I won't know til I try, so rolling back to that commit and re-running the test is also on my to do list.  When/if I learn any more, I'll provide an update here.

Comment: **UPDATE** - Confirmed this is an issue in C# (CLI) code.  Bug filed as [GEODE-7958](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7958).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with the test itself in this case.

The issue is with the assumption that a CacheListener is part of the subscription, but really it is just associated with the region and any event either local or remote can trigger the CacheListener. To determine the event source a user must inspect the EntryEvent for origin via the RemoteOrigin method as part of the Cachelistener event processing. The use of register interest in a key is a server side event and so unregistering interest in a key is also a server side action which should stop the push of events from the server to the client but a CacheListener will still be triggered for the local event. If you want the listener to no longer trigger then it must be set to null via the region AttributesMutator.